# Why would OpenGL ignore GL_DEPTH_TEST setting?

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl

I cannot figure out why some of my objects are being rendered on top of each other. I have Depth testing on.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
```

Do I need to draw by order of what is closest to the camera? (I thought OpenGL did that for you.)

[image: as you can see the cubes on the left are drawn correctly but the ones on the right are not]

Setup code:

```
 private  void setUpStates() {
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);        
    glLightModel(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, BufferTools.asFlippedFloatBuffer(new float[]{0, 0f, 0f, 1f}));         
    glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION,BufferTools.asFlippedFloatBuffer(new float[]{1, 1, 1, 1}) );

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE);   
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 50f);           
    camera.applyOptimalStates();       

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);



    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);       
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
}
```

Render Code:

```
private void render() {

    // Clear the pixels on the screen and clear the contents of the depth buffer (3D contents of the scene)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Reset any translations the camera made last frame update
    glLoadIdentity();
    // Apply the camera position and orientation to the scene
    camera.applyTranslations();
    glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, BufferTools.asFlippedFloatBuffer(500f, 100f, 500f, 1));        
    //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);       

    for(ChunkBatch cb : InterthreadHolder.getInstance().getBatches()){
        cb.draw(camera.x(), camera.y(), camera.z());
    }


}
```

The draw method in ChunkBatch:

```
    public void draw(float x, float y, float z) {
    shader.bind();
    shader.setUniform("cameraPosition", x,y,z);      
   for(ChunkVBO c : VBOs){  
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, c.vertexid);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, c.colorid);
        glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, c.normalid);
        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, c.visibleFaces * 6);          
    }
    ShaderProgram.unbind();     
}
```

Comment: Do you remember to clear the depth buffer? glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | ... );

Comment: Yes I do it in my render method

Comment: do you set the depth range anywhere?

Comment: Did you create your GL context with a depth buffer?  Also, regarding "Do I need to draw by order of what is closest to the camera? (I thought OpenGL did that for you)" - it actually doesn't.  GL will draw objects in the order that you send the data to it, and does no object sorting of it's own.  The depth buffer (and depth test) is what will test if an incoming object is in front of or behind what's already drawn, and discard it if behind.

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht - the initial glDepthRange is {0, 1} - there's no need to set it if you don't need to change it from those values.  See https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDepthRange.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten to ask for a depth buffer when creating my window:

Before:

```
Display.create(new PixelFormat(4,0,0,4));
```

After

```
Display.create(new PixelFormat(4,24,0,4));
```

Comment: I did the same thing once.  I bet you facepalmed a bit when you figured this out, didn't you?  It would be nice if drivers spit out a warning to `ARB_debug_output` when you do `glClear(DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` on a context that doesn't have a depth buffer.

Comment: Yeah its stupid that you can do that